# Printing argv and environ with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, argv, environ

For an exercise we need to print the elements in argv and environ (by looping through the other one). I can get it to print everything but for some reason the first and second pointer element are the same, which doesn't happen when using array indices. 
e.g.:

```
size_t idx = 0;
while (environ[idx])
{
     cout << idx << " = " << environ[idx] << '\n';
     ++idx;
}
```

prints (abbreviated):

```
0 = XDG_VTNR=7
1 = XDG_SESSION_ID=c4
2 = XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/*********
3 = CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=
4 = DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-qBmfhGvfX0,guid=33afede959ece95fbd4e3c055da5de6c
5 = QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=gtk
6 = GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/s2161915/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
```

trying to do the same with a pointer:

```
char *ptr = *environ;   
for (size_t idx = 0; *(argv + idx); ++idx)
{   
    if (ptr)                            // ptr isn't a nullptr
    {
        cout << idx << ": env: " << ptr << '\n'; 
        // make ptr point to next element in environ
        ptr = *(environ + idx);         
    } else
        break;                          // end of environ
}
```

prints the following (argc = 7):

```
0: env: XDG_VTNR=7
1: env: XDG_VTNR=7
2: env: XDG_SESSION_ID=c4
3: env: XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/*********
4: env: CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=
5: env: DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-qBmfhGvfX0,guid=33afede959ece95fbd4e3c055da5de6c
6: env: QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=gtk
```

The exact same things happens when I print argv by looping through environ, the first and second element print the same thing. I wanted to just loop from size_t = 1 but then it it won't print anything when no additional command line arguments are provided.. 
Why does this happen and not when using [idx]? I'm sure it's some pointer issue but pointers have always confused me so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the location of your line:

```
ptr = *(environ + idx);
```

As it stands, when the value `idx` is added, it takes the value of the current loop (before `idx` is incremented). So, after printing out the value on the first run through the `for` loop, the value of `idx` added to `environ` will be ZERO!

If you move that line of code to the **beginning** of your `for` loop, it will work!

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Within the loop

```
char *ptr = *environ;   
for (size_t idx = 0; *(argv + idx); ++idx)
{   
    if (ptr)                            // ptr isn't a nullptr
    {
        cout << idx << ": env: " << ptr << '\n'; 
        // make ptr point to next element in environ
        ptr = *(environ + idx);         
    } else
        break;                          // end of environ
}
```

The expression

```
ptr = *(environ + idx);
```

gives the same value of the pointer as the expression before the loop

```
char *ptr = *environ;
```

in the first iteration of the loop. That is `ptr` is not changed in the first iteration. `*(environ + 0)` is the same as `*environ` when `idx` is equal to `0`.

You could rewrite the loop like

```
char *ptr;   
for (size_t idx = 0; ( ptr = *(argv + idx) ) != nullptr; ++idx)
{   
    cout << idx << ": env: " << ptr << '\n'; 
}
```